# Cross-compile Qt5 (Mingw) with MySQL driver issue

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5

I tried a lot of things I read on documentations or tutorials... But I still can't cross-compile Qt with the MySQL library driver. Story begins:

I have to cross-compile Qt from Linux to Windows (32bits) using MinGW (`i686-w64-mingw32-` prefix to be precise). I downloaded `qtbase-opensource-src-5.9.4` and started to work like that:

```
$ ./configure -prefix [...]/qt-5.9.4 -xplatform win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32- -opengl desktop -no-sql-odbc -sql-sqlite -enable-shared -nomake examples -nomake tests -release
```

And it worked. Then, `make` and `make install` worked too. But I figured out that there was only the SQLite ".dll" in the `plugins/sqldrivers` repository. So I tried to compile the MySQL driver and... How can I do that?? If I add `-sql-mysql` to my `./configure ...` call, I have to following error:

```
ERROR: Feature 'sql-mysql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.mysql' failed.
```

I downloaded MySQL library from the official website to get `mysql-5.7.21-win32.zip`. But how to link it with qtbase sources? Adding `MYSQL_INCDIR=[...]/mysql-5.7.21-win32/include` and `MYSQL_LIBDIR=[...]/mysql-5.7.21-win32/lib` or just `MYSQL_PREFIX=[...]/mysql-5.7.21-win32` to my `./configure ...` command results to the same error message.

Any idea please?

**EDIT:**

I tried to compile the driver like that (with the `qmake` I built previously):

```
$ cd qtbase-opensource-src-5.9.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
$ [/*prefix of my previous build*/]/qt-5.9.4/bin/qmake .
```

And the result is:

```
Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.
```

Comment: Did you cross-compile MySQL as well?

Comment: @JvO No. But I think it should works because this lib contains the .dll/.lib, the headers and some useless .exe in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok everyone, I found the solution: do a clean checkout or add `-recheck-all` to the `./configure` command when you want to add a lib like MySQL in my case. Easy isn't it? To make it clear, here is the command I used:

```
./configure -prefix [...] -xplatform win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32- -opengl desktop -no-sql-odbc -sql-sqlite -plugin-sql-mysql MYSQL_PREFIX=[...] -enable-shared -nomake examples -nomake tests -release -recheck-all
```

That was just a refresh problem, but I prefer to let this answer because it's pretty hard to realize.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you tried in your EDIT, should I think be:

```
$ cd qtbase-opensource-src-5.9.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX= [...]/mysql-5.7.21-win32/include
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it produces the same result: `Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined.`

Comment: @N0un Do you have MySQL header files and `libmysqlclient.so` under `[...]/mysql-5.7.21-win32`

Comment: @N0un, header files are usually under  `../include` , as I updated my answer

Comment: Tks for your answer but... If I launch this `qmake` in `qtbase-opensource-src-5.9.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers`, there is no error message but the Makefile doesn't contains any directive to produce MySQL (only sub-sqlite...). If I launch it in sub directory `/mysql` it produces the same error message than in my EDIT.